# Loading pygame images as a module

Tags: python, pygame

I have a lot of images i need to load into a Pygame program. Can I load all these from a separate script which I load into my main program as a module and be used from within the main program? Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you just have the files with meaningful names.

You can then load the images into a dictionary, with the filename being the key.

An example use:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

IMAGE_PATH = "/images"
images_dict = dict()

images = [ f for f in listdir(IMAGE_PATH) if isfile(join(IMAGE_PATH,f)) and f.endswith('png') ]

for filename in images:
    images_dict[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]] = pygame.image.load(join(IMAGE_PATH,filename))
```

then you could use images in the following fashion:

```
image = images_dict['fox']
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do, is having a separate file called constants.py or images.py in the same directory as your main file. In the images.py for example I load an image like this
X = pygame.image.load("image_path.extension")

Then the only thing I have to do is import the images file from the main file and the X image is directly accessible in the main file :) hope that helps!

(edit) What I do is exactly what you said, i.e. load the images like that in the load_images.py file and then from the main program I import the file like that:

```
from load_images.py import *
```

Then again from the main file I can access all the images like that:

```
image1 = pic1
image2 = pic2
.....
```

etc.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. this is how i understood it.

Comment: first program has the images loading like below

pic1 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsu.png").convert_alpha()
pic2 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsuL2.png").convert_alpha()
pic3 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsuL3.png").convert_alpha()
pic4 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsd.png").convert_alpha()
pic5 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsdL2.png").convert_alpha()
pic6 = pygame.image.load("data/img/qsdL3.png").convert_alpha()

now i save the file as load_images.pythen from my main program I write the like below
from load_images import pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6
new_image1=pic1 etc.
like that?

Answer (score 0):

After considering both answers above what I simply did was write a script where I loaded all images and created a dictionary called image_dict with the image names as the keys and saved the program as "load_images.py"
Then from the second program I did a "from load_images.py import image_dict".
now the keys gave me the images.

Thank you.